# Getting resources outside of src folder in a JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I've been searching around for hours trying to fix this problem and found multiple posts about similar problems, but nothing I find seems to do the exact thing I'm trying.

I have a `res` folder at the same level of my `src` folder which I use for things like images and text files. I can easily spit out the text file in Eclipse by simply doing:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("res/misc/foo.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

However, the problem starts when I package this up in a runnable JAR file. I found multiple threads pointing this out:

```
Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/misc/foo.txt");
```

However, this only works if the resources are in the same `source` folder as the class. And indeed, when i move the `res` folder into `src` it can find the resource, but that's not how I want to organize my project.

Is there some way to do this that I missed, or should I change my folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511835/14009135) already said:

Create the folder `res` as a source folder (just like `src`). Put your files there and then you can access them the same way you access files in your `src` i.e.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/misc/foo.txt");
```

In Eclipse you can simply create a new file as "Source Folder". You could also just copy the `scr` folder and rename it to lets say `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the path with something like:

```
String path = <YourClassName>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Then a quick test to check if the directory is there:

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] dirList = folder.listFiles();

for (File list : dirList) {
    if (list.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + list.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change your structure, such as make `res` a source folder as well (you can have more than one source folder). It's not really about *being* a source folder, it's about getting your resources to be copied into the same tree that makes up the contents of the resulting jar.

Comment: The resource files are already packaged into the jar, and res is a source folder as well. When I open up the jar with something like WinRAR, i can see that all the folders are there. It's just a directory issue I'm having

Answer (score 0):

Use maven resource plugin,
The resources plugin copies files from input resource directories to an output directory.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Assume we want to copy resource files from the directory input-resources to the directory output-resources and we want to exclude all files ending with the extension .png.

just like excludes you can include files using

These requirements are satisfied with this configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>output-resources</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>input-resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.png</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```